# What does Diva Sahibi mean in Spanish?

Tags: colombia, nombres-propios

> Antes de irme al amanecer dibujé en un papel las líneas de su mano, y se las di a
>   leer a la Diva Sahibí para conocer su alma. (Garcia Marquez, Memorias de mis putas tristes)

Translation:

> Before I left at dawn I drew the lines of her hand on a piece of paper and gave it to Diva Sahibi for a
>   reading so I could know her soul (Grossman).

Is Diva Sahibi a person's name or a name referring in general to people who read palms, do fortune-telling, etc.? I suspect the latter might be the case as there are no other references the this noun in the book.

Answer (score 3):

I had to get to the third page in the Google results for "Diva Sahibí", but I found [this](http://ramestr3.blogspot.com.es/2011/10/la-diva-sahibi.html?zx=3a1515aaeef46935):

> Hablando con el Cheo Feliciano, recordé que por mucho tiempo estuve creyendo que la “Diva Sahibí”, una adivina que mi madre describe como una mujer toda pintorreteada, con el cabello recogido en un moño de dama antigua, con dedos largos, y cejas encontradas que tenia su consultorio en la vieja “calle Caldas”, -era la versión barranquillera de Lady Macbeth, el famoso monstruo de “pechos perversos” creado por Shakespeare.
>   Pero, el Cheo, me corrigió, me dijo que no, que “la Diva Sahibi” era una mentalista común y corriente, pero que cogiò mucha fama porque en una visita que Jorge Eliécer Gaitán, hizo a Barranquilla, a mediados de enero o febrero de 1948, ella le leyó la palma de la mano y le dijo que Juan Roa Sierra, un joven esquizofrénico que vivía en el barrio Ricaurte de Bogotá, lo mataría al mediodía del 9 de abril de ese año. De modo que el 9 de abril, cuando mataron a Gaitán, y la gente se enloqueció, el ñato Grau -un personaje popular en Barranquilla-, se fue corriendo a la casa de la Diva, tocó la puerta y como esta preguntó: ¿Quién es? El Ñato le dijo: ¡Adivina!

It seems that it was a real person from Barranquilla. Apart from that, "diva" means the following:

> **[divo, va](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E1iImRZ)**
>
> Del lat. *divus* 'divino'.
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de un artista del mundo del espectáculo, y en especial de un cantante de ópera: Que goza de fama superlativa. U. t. c. s. U.
>      t. en sent. peyor.
> 2. adj. poét. divino. Apl. a deidades gentílicas, a los emperadores romanos a quienes se concedían honores divinos después de su muerte,
>      y, por ext., a otros personajes ilustres. *Divo Augusto.*
> 3. m. y f. poét. dios (‖ deidad de cualquier religión).

Comment: It is worth indicating that the Caribbean Colombia (the region where G. G. Márquez was from) has a big population of Lebaneses from late 19th century (they even have [an article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebanese_Colombians)). For example, Shakira is one of their descendants. This to say that _Sahibi_ may sound like a very strange name for a country like Colombia, but it may be related to this ethnic group.

Comment: @fedorqui good point, yeah it kind of sounds Arabic to me.

Comment: It probably comes from _sahib_ https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahib which was quite commonly used in English at the period when we still ruled India. (The English Wikipedia entry is much richer by the way).

Comment: @fedorqui Or, given that the character is presented as a "mentalist", maybe it is just an "artistic name", chosen just because it sounds good; that would explain "Diva" being in uppercase. Of course, the latin ("Diva") and Indian ("Sahibí") inspiration when chosing the name appear to be very clear.